# Apache Zeppelin - zeppelin.cmd shows no result

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I unpacked the full version on 0.81 Apache Zeppelin on windows 10. I navigated to the C:\Zeppelin\bin and typed in zeppelin.cmd

I do not get any output after that  C:\Zeppelin\bin" just gets repeated. And i can clearly see zeppelin.cmd in the dir/p of the folder

How do i debug this

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I recently encountered this problem as well. After going through the cmd files in the bin folder, I found that there is an accidental `'}'` where there should be a `')'`. It came after set `ZEPPELIN_JMX_PORT="9996"` in the `common.cmd` file. Once I changed this it worked fine.

Comment: This hasn't changed anything for me, still getting no result from zeppelin.cmd (or zeppelin-daemon.sh start, although that one seems to at least generate a terminal window that hangs around for 2-3 seconds before disappearing). Well spotted though!

Comment: I believe zeppelin-daemon.sh start is only for Mac, although I also tried it to see if it would work and had the same terminal window pop up and close. For context though, have you set your JAVA_HOME environment variable to your JDK file location?

Comment: this was the case for me and your solution was a life saver for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to bin -> create folder zeppelin-web-angular/dist and mkdir -p zeppelin-web/dist
2. Copy zeppelin-web-angular-0.9.0-preview2.war and zeppelin-web-0.9.0-preview2.war into dist folder respectively
3. unzip it, jar -xvf yourWARfileName.war
4. remove war files from dist folder
5. start Zepplin.cmd